# Does List Metadata get copied into document properties

Tags: content-type, metadata

If you specify a document as being of a particular content type, and then move the document, the metadata associated with that document moves with it, regardless of what library the document is moved to.

Does the same apply to metadata that is associated with a document in a list or library?  In other words if I have a Library with custom columns and I move a document into a different library, does the metadata move with the document, or is it lost the moment the doc is removed from the library?

Thanks

EDIT ____________________________

I've created a document library and had the library support a Content Type with metadata fields.  I uploaded a document and filled in the fields.  I then downloaded the document to my desktop.  All of the fields where properties of the document.  However, there was not Content Type property (there was when I inspected the document in the Library.)  I then uploaded the document into a standard Document Library and all custom properties were removed.  If I associate a workflow with my Content Type and move the document into record center, is the Content Type lost?

Comment: Why you simply didn't try it?